# Sending an HTML e-mail with an inline image with JavaMail - Slow image loading?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

When I send an HTML e-mail using JavaMail, and include an inline image in the HTML, the image takes 2-3 seconds to load when read in either Gmail or Yahoo.

The image that I am using is a small .png that is about 200 bytes in size.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class EmailTest 
{   
    static String from = "Your_Gmail_Account_Name";  // (e.g., "name" if your account is "name@gmail.com"
    static String password = "Your_Gmail_Password";    
    static String to = "Send_Here@gmail.com";
    static String subject = "test";
    static String body = "<h1>The image in this e-mail is slow to load.</h1><img src=\"cid:my-image\">"; 
    static String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");  
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try 
        {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));    
            InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            message.setSubject(subject);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

            MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(new File("src\\icon.png"));
            imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
            imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<my-image>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

            try 
            {
                transport.connect(host, from, password);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();

                System.out.println("e-mail sent.");
            } 
            catch (MessagingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (AddressException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Does anyone know why the image is so slow to load?

UPDATE:

When reading the e-mail produced by the above code in Thunderbird, the image wouldn't even load, but would only show up as an attachment.

But if I remove this line:

```
imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<my-image>");
```

and replace it with these two lines:

```
imagePart.addHeader("Content-ID", "<my-image>");
imagePart.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
```

then the image actually loads in Thunderbird, and loads instantaneously.

However, the image is still slow to load in both Gmail and Yahoo.

Comment: This is not really a good question for SO. You are actually asking why GMail and Yahoo are slow to present the image which is causes by a "feature" of their service. It's totally outside the control of anyone except the developers/maintainers of said service.

Comment: I would have to respectfully disagree.  I am asking whether or not the way I am constructing the e-mail object in my code is having any effect on the load time of the image.  It's not at all clear to me that this is a problem with a "feature" of the Gmail or Yahoo service, as opposed to my code.

Comment: Finally, found a answer that works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they're running a virus scanner on it?  Try Thunderbird.

Comment: The image does not even load in Thunderbird.  It just shows up as an attachment.

Comment: I actually got it to work in Thunderbird (see update to original post).  However, the slow loading still persists in Gmail and Yahoo.

Comment: Hopefully it's now clear to you that this is a problem with Gmail and Yahoo, not with your program.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill and the other poster mentioned, the problem is not an issue with JavaMail, but appears to be an issue with Gmail and Yahoo scanning embedded inline images sent in e-mails.

The solution is to not embed any inline images in your HTML e-mail with a Content-ID, but to place a src attribute in your img tags in your HTML that refers to your images that are sitting on a remote host.

This will make your images load very quickly when they are sent inside an HTML e-mail.

In other words:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class EmailTest 
{   
    static String from = "Your_Gmail_Account_Name";  // Your Gmail account name (e.g., "name" if your account is "name@gmail.com"
    static String password = "Your_Gmail_Password";   // Your Gmail password
    static String to = "Send_Here@gmail.com";
    static String subject = "test";
    static String body = "<html><body><h1>The image in this e-mail loads very fast.</h1><img src=\"http://www.your_host.com/path/to/image/icon.png\"></body></html>"; 

    static String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");  
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try 
        {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));    
            InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            message.setSubject(subject);    
            message.setContent(body, "text/html");

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

            try 
            {
                transport.connect(host, from, password);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();

                System.out.println("e-mail sent.");
            } 
            catch (MessagingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (AddressException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```